# Declaring a number (runningScore) that can be subtracted from and new number retained in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am looking to set up a calculator of sorts whereby there is a targetScore and when you click on a button it subtracts a given number from targetScore and the result becomes the new targetScore and the process continues until targetScore is 0.

I have read Steven Kochans book, and several objective c for dummies (quite appropriate for me), have looked at tutorials on lynda.com and read about a million threads on here but have yet to find a suitable answer (or at least one I have recognised as suitable). I am very new to objective c and am more than prepared to do the hard yards and research if someone can just point me in the right direction.

I am not asking for you to write code for me just point me in the right direction, i.e. do I declare targetScore as NSObject/NSNumber/NSDecimalNumber/NSMutableArray etc and how do I get the new targetScore to be retained and replace the old targetScore.

I would like to thank you in advance for any help proffered,

Comment: Please retag your question if it's iOS or OSX application that you are working on.

Comment: u can use label for your targetscore if you want, the code will then depend if your targetscore is prefix, or randomly generated.  and the button that subtract the number, is it random number? if no, how do you input the number? If what you want are bit and pieces similar to a calculator function, you could do the itune U calculator tutorial. Learn the basic, and tweak the functions around to what you want.

Comment: Also, is the number whole number, contain negative, or decimal point.

Comment: In answer to your questions, I am using a UILabel as my output, targetScore is set and is not random, the subtracted number is not random but will be the value of the sender tag of the button. Have done the calculator tutorial and have tweaked it for my uses however after each operation the calculator resets to zero. What I am bring to establish is how I can get the calculator to hold the new number after each subtraction and not reset back to to its original declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Baby steps. Get the smallest possible data format to satisfy your needs. In your case - you'd be good with <del>`short`</del> `char` (for score from -128 up to 127) or <del>`unsigned short`</del> `unsigned char` (for score from 0 to 255). If not, `int` or `NSInteger` will definitely cover all your bases (unless score is higher than 2^31). It's a simple integer and you don't need objects (like `NSNumber` or `NSDecimalNumber`) for simple math you are going to do.

Comment: Ya I think you have [`short`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Short_integer) confused with `char`.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Thanks for the replies, think maybe I was getting ahead of myself and making things too complicated. However if I declare int targetScore; targetScore = 501; for example how do I then get targetScore to change as and when numbers are subtracted fromm it. Again many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with one of XCode template project, I would recommend 'Single view application'.
This will give you a UIViewController, and a Xib, whre you can place a button or other interface elements.

You can declare targetScore as a property of the UIViewController.